# Python: Making a Magic 8 Ball game, why do i keep getting syntax errors? Here's the code, test it if you want

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is my code. When I ask a question I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random

answer1=("Absolutely!")
answer2=("No way Pedro!")
answer3=("Go for it tiger.")

print ("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball game - use it to answer your questions...")

question = input("Ask me for any advice and I'll help you out. Type in your question and then press enter for an answer.")

print ("shaking....\n"*4)

choice=random.randint(1,3)

if choice == 1:
    **strong text**answer==answer1
elif choice == 2:
    answer==answer2
else:
    answer==answer3

print (answer)
```

This error comes up when I ask any question

```
Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball game - use it to answer your questions...
Ask me for any advice and I'll help you out. Type in your question and then press enter for an answer.should i play xbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Magic8Ball.py", line 11, in <module>
    question = input("Ask me for any advice and I'll help you out. Type in your question and then press enter for an answer.")
  File "<string>", line 1
    should i play xbox
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Is that `**strong_text**` really in the code or was it a mistake from copy/paste?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Edit your question to include the entire error message.

Comment: updated the question there now

Comment: Are you using Python version 2 or 3?  If you're using version 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: Ah, that worked, thanks! Was confused because I must be using version 3 in school, I was using version 2 here. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `==` which is a comparison operator to assign variables. It should be `=` instead. Also, you forgot to declare answer: `answer = ""`.

```
import random

answer1=("Absolutely!")
answer2=("No way Pedro!")
answer3=("Go for it tiger.")

print ("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball game - use it to answer your questions...")

question = input("Ask me for any advice and I'll help you out. Type in your question and then press enter for an answer.")

print ("shaking....\n"*4)

choice=random.randint(1,3)
answer = ""
if choice == 1:
    answer=answer1
elif choice == 2:
    answer=answer2
else:
    answer=answer3

print (answer)
```

If you are using Python2.7 use `raw_input` instead of `input`